# Editing a wiki on a github repo

Tags: git, github, wiki

I am trying to edit and make changes on another persons wiki for their repo. I cloned it locally with the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/***/***.wiki.git
```

I then edited it and completed the desired changes. Now, how do I go about pushing said changes? Do I need to open a pull request for this and how would I go about it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried to push changes on the same remote origin branch but I get the Permission denied (publickey) error.

Answer (score 8):

There are two problems here.  The first is that you actually seemed to have cloned at ssh linked git repository such as

`git@github.com:/***/**.wiki.git`

And thus why it is saying `Permission denied (publickey)`.  If you'd cloned a `https` git repo then you would type username / password.

As to how to edit a github wiki locally - By default the branch is master.  If you choose to work on sub-branches to separate the work, then you'll need to merge to your local master branch and push.  There doesn't seem to be a way to have pull requests for wiki pages.

---

In summary:

1. If not done, setup your public/private ssh key in github - https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/
2. Checkout your repo locally - `git clone git@github.com:/***/**.wiki.git`
3. **Optionally** branch so as to separate the work(s) - `git checkout -b some_branch`
4. Edit your wiki pages with a markdown editor (I used IntelliJ with a Markdown plugin - it can display the markdown on one page and the rendered page next to it, which is nice.)
5. Add and commit your work:
   `git add page.md
   git commit -m "Added blah blah instructions"`
6. **Optionally** merge back to master:
   `git checkout master
   git merge some_branch`
7. Push it back to the github repo - `git push`

Remember, you can't seem to be able to do pull requests with github wiki pages (since the only branch available through Github is master).

Answer (score 2):

**Not possible!**

Though, you could open an issue to ask the mainter(s) to [make the wiki publicly editable](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/changing-access-permissions-for-wikis).